# Mapping the artefacts of one nexus Repository instance to another instance

Tags: maven, npm, migration, repository, nexus

I'm new to the nexus world. I wanna move all the artefacts from one nexus repository to another nexus repository instance.(or you can say I wanna migrate the repos)

below is the nexus instances I've and their current version.

one Nexus Instance (Source Repository instance): **Nexus Repository Manager OSS** (2.14 version)
2nd Nexus Instance (Destination Repository Instance):**Sonatype Nexus** (2.11 version)

Is there any way to do this:-

I know one solution which is a manual solution, one can manually move the repository from source to destination storage.

https://community.talend.com/s/article/Manually-migrating-artifacts-from-one-Nexus-environment-to-another-S5taY?language=en_US

I went through this solution thread of nexus community as well but not able to find out. ):

https://community.sonatype.com/t/to-copy-single-repository-from-old-instance-to-new/1679

Is there any 2nd way to achieve this like can we use any Jenkins plugins, or some script that can help us to achieve above or any rest api's way?

It would be very helpful if someone answer this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why to migrate and not simply upgrade the installation.. ?

Comment: I just wanted to move a single repo instead all. Since the destination instance I'm planning to upgrade, but the source instance I used for Poc's, So will not upgrade that one as of now so thinking to migrate(copy) a single repo